# React-Native install on Windows Machine not finding $PATH

Tags: android, windows, react-native, npm

I'm installing react-native first y installing react-native-cli

Based on the instructions at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html...

I installed Android Studio and then added the sdk path to my $PATH, so if I `echo $PATH`, the path

```
/c/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

is included. Then I...

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

which resulted in

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native -> 
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 2.303s
```

but it is still not finding react-native ...

```
react-native-cli --version
bash: react-native-cli: command not found
```

Why can't I find my react-native-install?

Comment: Why does your path start with `/c/` if you are using Windows? Should it not be `C:\\`?

Comment: I copied that portion from the output of echo $PATH. If I copy it from the Android Studio system settings, it reads as: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: And to be sure, you have restarted since installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native-cli is not a command. With this npm i -g react-native-cli you can use the command -> react-native 
you can now use react-native init "project"
then npm start

Comment: typing react-native --version outputs: 
bash: react-native: command not found

Comment: hummm open a new term and test

Comment: tried that, same result: bash: react-native: command not found

Comment: or try to install git for windows and use(after install) left clic and "git bash here"

Comment: I'm already using Git Bash as my shell, so Git for Windows is installed

Comment: try open as administrator git bash -> npm i -g react-native-cli -> close the windows -> git bash here -> react-native init test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193964/discussion-between-tetar-and-shotdsherrif).

Comment: npm installed react-native-cli to the path AppData/Roaming... which I added to my $PATH and it was fixed. Thank you tetar

Answer (score 0):

```
Install Chocolatey Chocolatey is a popular package manager for Windows. So at first, we need to install it on our system.

To install Chocolaty, Open Command Prompt with administrator privileges and run the command below.

@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8.

npm install –g react-native-cli

More Detail Follow this
https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-react-native-on-windows-10/
```